# How do you define types in a tuple in a function

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

I have just started with F# and functional programming. I want to know how I can make a function taking a tuple where I define that the first value have to be a string, instead of the standard int.

Example:

A function which replicates a string, `s`, `n` times and returns it. What i have right now is this:

```
let rec pow2 = function
    | (s:string,0) -> ""
    | (s:string,n) -> s + pow2(s,n-1)
```

This works, but I think that there is a better way than defining `s:string` every case.

(I know `String.replicate`, this is not for the sake of the effect, but learning)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, no type annotations are required here. The `""` return value in the the first pattern match is a sufficient enough hint for the compiler:

```
> let rec pow2 = function
    | (s,0) -> ""
    | (s,n) -> s + pow2(s,n-1);;

val pow2 : string * int -> string
```

Answer (score 4):

You only need the type annotation on the first case -- the F# compiler can infer that the first element of the tuple must be a `string` in the rest of the cases.

```
let rec pow2 = function
    | (s:string,0) -> ""
    | (s,n) -> s + pow2(s,n-1)
```

It's just a matter of style, but I think it's a little easier to read if you write the function like this:

```
let rec pow2 (s, n) =
    match n with
    | 0 -> ""
    | _ -> s + pow2(s, n-1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it like this, where the type of the tuple is given in the function definition:

```
let rec pow2 ((s, n) : string * int) =
    match n with
    | 0 -> ""
    | _ -> s + pow2 (s, n - 1)
```

Note that elements of a tuple are seperated by `*` in the explicit type annotation. Also, as Stephen pointed out, the type inference system will, in this example, be smart enough to figure out the type of tuple because we match `n` with an integer and because we add a string (`""`) to `s`.